# Object-like type definition: can someone explain?

Tags: typescript

I'm working with a library that uses the following type definition:

```js
interface Auth0ContextInterface<TUser extends User = User> extends AuthState<TUser> {
  getAccessTokenSilently: {
    (options: GetTokenSilentlyOptions & { detailedResponse: true }): Promise<GetTokenSilentlyVerboseResponse>;
    (options?: GetTokenSilentlyOptions): Promise<string>;
    (options: GetTokenSilentlyOptions): Promise<GetTokenSilentlyVerboseResponse | string>;
  };
}  
...
```

Can someone explain what the `getAccessTokenSilently` definition means? I assumed that it was another way of joining multiple types, but none of these work in the codebase I'm working on.

Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a function overload type definition.

The `getAccessTokenSilently` method in your interface has 3 different definitions:

```ts
(options: GetTokenSilentlyOptions & { detailedResponse: true }): 
Promise<GetTokenSilentlyVerboseResponse>

(options?: GetTokenSilentlyOptions): 
Promise<string>;

(options: GetTokenSilentlyOptions): 
Promise<GetTokenSilentlyVerboseResponse | string>;
```

Comment: Ah ok - thank you for your quick answer :) So as I understand it, if the method in question matches one of those definitions, it should be valid? Because I've got the following definition but I'm still getting an error:

`getAccessTokenSilently: async () => Promise.resolve('token')`

This should match the 2nd definition, right?

Comment: Yes, it should match it !